# Find certain text in text string in one column and delete or replace with blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have a constant problem of having to remove "LLC, Inc"..etc from the end of companies names from multiple Excel files. I was hoping to write a VBA code that can do this for me and allow me to add new things to delete or replace as I find different iterations (ex. L.L.C. vs LLC vs , LLC)

I have tried to google solutions but all I have found are 1 for 1 find and replace options.

This is the closest I have gotten so far but it is only a 1 for 1 find and replace.

```
Sub Remove()

Dim findtext As String
Dim replacetext As String

findtext = (", LLC")
replacetext = ("")

Set Sheet = Sheets("Public Utilities")

Sheet.Cells.Replace what:=findtext, Replacement:=replacetext, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: You could loop through the various options, or investigate regular expressions. In the first case, `findtext` would be an array to be looped through.

Comment: @SJR Would that look something like findtext = Array ("example 1", example 2")? any other code needed to make it a loop?

Comment: VBA can definitely help you out. But you can also check out Power Query.

Comment: That is correct, as per answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a loop to include variations:

```
Sub Remove()
    Dim findtext
    Dim replacetext As String

    replacetext = ("")

    Set Sheet = Sheets("Public Utilities")

    For Each findtext In Array(", LLC", ", LLC Inc", "junk")
        Sheet.Cells.Replace what:=findtext, Replacement:=replacetext, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next findtext
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great! works like a charm. Thank you! Can you elaborate why you don't need the `As Sting` after the `findtext` at the beginning?

Comment: @narsil  I wanted it to be a ***Variant***